# Gatling 3.7 setup duration time for the whole test

Tags: java, scala, gatling

could someone help me ??
how can I convert the below scale code to the Gatling 3.7 java?

values:
testConfig.vUsers == 5
testConfig.rampup == testConfig.vUsers * 4 seconds = 20 seconds

```scala
setUp(
        Demo_Scenario.inject(rampUsers(testConfig.vUsers) during (testConfig.rampup))
    ).throttle(
        reachRps(109).in(436 seconds),
        holdFor(64 minutes)
    ).protocols(httpProtocol)
        .assertions(
            forAll.responseTime.mean.lte(200),
            forAll.responseTime.percentile3.lte(200),
            forAll.successfulRequests.percent.gte(95)
        )
}
```

and this one:

```scala
setUp(
        Demo_scenario.inject(rampUsers(testConfig.vUsers) during (testConfig.rampup))
    ).protocols(httpProtocol)
        .assertions(
            forAll.responseTime.mean.lte(200),
            forAll.responseTime.percentile3.lte(200),
            forAll.successfulRequests.percent.gte(95)
        )
}
```

and finally, how can I set up the duration for the full test let's say I want the test still running for 1 h ??

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There's some misunderstanding on some Gatling concepts here:

- you define the users arrival rate over time with an **injection profile**
- the virtual users perform a **scenario**
- `throttle` merely sets a limit on your rps, it doesn't make your test last longer
- `rampUsers(5) during (20)` is going to start a total of 5 users over 20 seconds, meaning 1 every 4 seconds

This is all explained in the official [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/) and the [free online courses](https://gatling.io/academy/).

So your test duration depends on:

- how long your injection profile lasts
- how long your virtual users take to perform their scenario

If `Demo_Scenario` only lasts 5 second, your test is going to complete after 25 seconds.
If you want your test to last 1 hour:

- either inject users for a long period
- or make your scenario last longer, eg with [loops](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/#loop-statements)

The suited solution really depends on your use case: do you want fresh new users or reuse the same few ones.

Note: Gatling 3.7 is deprecated, current version is 3.8.3.